# Change background colour in navbar if url contains right string

Tags: php, html, css, parameter-passing

I would like to make navbar, in which background colour of one element would change if user would be on that subpage.
Code for checking if url contains chosen string:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
//echo ($url);
if (strpos($url, 'index.php') == true) {
    //echo 'Current page contains index.php';
    $atm = "#2275A8";
} else {
    $atm = "#00427A";
} 
?>
```

This is part from same file saved as .php file

```
<?php 
    header("Content-type: text/css");
?>
.ico1 {
    background: <?php echo $atm; ?>;
}
```

If i put my "ckecking part" od code on index, it is working nicely; returning true or false, but for some reason it's not passing parameter into style file.
So now i put "checking part" into style file but, no mater on which subpage i am, its returning same result (always true even if 'index' is not part of url).

Any  idea on how to deal with this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define classes with style you want in style.css file and change the class of element you want to change style of dynamically in php file like in the example below.

**style.css**

```
.ico1 {
   background: color1;
}

.ico2 {
   background: color2;
}
```

**index.php** (or the file containing navbar you want to change)

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($url, 'index.php') == true) {
    //echo 'Current page contains index.php';
    $atm = "ico1";
} else {
    $atm = "ico2";
} 
?>

...

<div class="<?php echo $atm;?>"> // navbar
```

Comment: Style file is .php file.  In index.php it works fine :)

Comment: I don't get it. is this a good answer or you're looking for something else? :)

Comment: It hasn't solve my problem, sorry. I want to have variable $atm inside of my style (.php) file but its not passing (so i tried moving all php for checking into style file but then it's not working - always returning same result, no matter on whisc supage i am)

Comment: could you add checking part directly to the style of the element you want to change? like <div style="<?php checking ... ?>"></div>. It's maybe a better solution to write both styles as classes in css file and than just change classes in navbar

Comment: It "works" - i put echo in it to determine result.:) BUT it is still not passing variable into style.php file, so colour is not changing.

Comment: could you try defining 
.ico1 {
    background: #2275A8;
} and .ico2 {
    background: #00427A;
} in style.php to be static and then change classes of navbar with php dynamically in index.php file?

Comment: sounds good :) So how do i do that (change depending on url)?

Comment: so you check url in subpage file (the file that has navbar that changes color) and css is always the same. if true <navbar class="<?php echo 'ico1'?>" else <navbar class="<?php echo 'ico2'?>"

Comment: so you mean i would be having style for each .icoX inside of subpage, and not in separate style flie? :)

Comment: (navbar is in separated file, i used php include() on every page)

Comment: i've changed the answer to ilustrate. basically you would have styles for both subpages in one style file and change classes of navbar depending on a style you want on them. you can perform that check in navbar file also.

Comment: I understand now, let me try that, i will let you know in a tiny bit :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have the two css classes and make a conditional in the element you want the class be applied:

**CSS**

```
.ico1-0 {
  background: #2275A8;
}

.ico1-1 {
  background: #00427A;
}
```

**PHP**

```
[...]
<div class="<?php echo (strpos($url, 'index.php') === true) ? 'ico1-0' : 'ico1-1'; ?>"></div>
[...]
```

Comment: Solution seem really good to solve what i want. But the problem is when i add your PHP to class of div (that i want to change background on) my page just goes blank after that PHP (page is showing only content in front of place where i pasted your syntax (like it would be missing ending like > or } something, i dont know).

Comment: I've made a mistake, the call for strpos was incorrect, updated

Answer (score 0):

[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) will never return true. Either it will return false or it return integer. So try like below.

```
if (strpos($url, 'index.php') !== false)
```

Comment: I changed it the way you suggested, i still have the same problem; only returning same result, no matter on which subpage i am located.